# Typo3 GP variables in TSSETUP

Tags: variables, search, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use typo3 7.6.10

I learn how get a url variable and store it in other variable for fluid in TSSETUP:

```
lib.pippomio = TEXT
lib.pippomio.data = GP:cat
```

example url: `index.php?id=10&cat=pino`

I print the variable in my template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pippomio"  />
```

Ok it works.

Now i need to print the variable in input by Search Indexed Engine:

```
<input class="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword" id="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword" type="text" name="tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][sword]" value="progetto">
```

How can i store in lib.pippomio the POST Variable "tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][sword]" ???

I tried

```
lib.pippomio.data = GP:tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][sword]
```

But it doesn't works.
I want to print the word searched in an other place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pipe "|" to get it

`lib.pippomio.data = GP:tx_indexedsearch_pi2|search|sword`

[TYPOSCRIPT Reference => getText](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html)